# How to protect yourself from people downloading / stealing flash games from your websites

Tags: flash, apache-flex, copy-protection

i am developing games in flash as5. Just started 1 month ago.

I knew years back when it was possible to just go to a website and then click on menu extras ->site information->media files and than download the game to play offline or even decompile.

nowadays i see this is not anymore possible, for example:

http://www.miniclip.com/games/robo-rampage/en/

http://www.casinoeuro.com/en/casino-games/table-games/txs-holdem-poker/0,1-5

how do they prevent this? i am coming from php and i know in this scripting language you can't hide the source. how is that in flash?

the only thing i can download here are: loaders.swf or gameloader.swf.

**Would it be possible for someone to completely recreate these games?**

if you don't have a decompiler, here is what is inside such a loaders.swf/gameloader.swf, click on Actionscript:
http://software.pedrofaustino.com/swfinfo/sidebar/index.html?file=loader.swf

Comment: I sincerely doubt that the "work-stealing" tag is appropriate

Comment: `i am coming from php and i know in this scripting language you can't hide the source.` ... so if you right-click in your browser and choose "view source", you see the actual PHP-code??? When did they introduce that? ;)

Comment: the html source of course. so the equivalent would be the "true" swf for actionscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method that I use, is upon start up check [loaderInfo.url](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#url) (in as3) and make sure it matches the url of your website (or substring look for the domain) and if it's not there, then someone put it on another web site (stole it) or is trying to run it locally (which url will say localhost).  This however does not prevent any decompilers to run, but there are obfuscators for that such as [swfencrypt](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/)